# Meaning of Out[0]

Tags: output

After some long computations, I obtain

> %//ExpandAll

`Out[0]`

I want to know the meaning of `Out[0]`. Does this mean my expression % is zero?

Comment: It probably means your kernel died during the last computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this does not mean your answer is 0. If you look at the documentation of Out then it says that: Out[n]
is a global object that is assigned to be the value produced on the n-th output line. Out[0] is undefined since you always start evaluation at line 1. The result you get is most probably caused by a statement of the form `%` as a first evaluation or `%%` when only 1 line was evaluated or `%0`.

To get rid of such results try to avoid using the `%` operation and assign results of calculations to symbols. So, e.g., instead of writing

```
(x+1)^2

Expand[%]
```

use

```
p = (x+1)^2;

Expand[p]
```

Comment: I'm confused, I thought the Out function was a good standard practice. But, I prefer temp variables to retain useful values, all the time. I like your answer. But when are Out values useful? Perhaps, just true temporary values?

Comment: @prog9910 there's really nothing wrong with using `%` in an interactive session with a notebook. Eventually when you know you want to do something with the result of a calculation you start assigning a variable as shown in this answer. But the issue you are seeing is explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259302/meaning-of-out0#comment646688_259302): your kernel quit during the long computation, so when you call `%` there is no previous output to refer to.

Comment: As Jason points out: its not bad practice when you're using the notebook interactively. Even then I would advise to use Out[n] instead of % since the value of % changes with every evaluation and as is the case above: its not always clear what its value used to be at some point in the notebook. The reason that using Out[n] is not always the best choice is that either (1) you have infinite history length (i.e. Out[n] is stored for all n), which might induce crashes or (2) you have a finite history length but then the value of Out[n] might be removed at some point.